# Key press to reach the position

Tags: python, pyautogui

What should I use to write a function that would press the keys until a certain object (png image) reaches a certain position on the screen.
For example, a png object has its center point at:
x = 800, y = 600
and is to move to:
x = 423.y = 600
and in this case the function will press the left arrow until the center of the png object is in the final location (the object moves at its own speed, independent of us).

I tried to do it in pyautogui due to the possibility of selecting objects by means of photos and as for movement, I found only information about the movement of the mouse.

I am a layman, not a programmer, please understand

EDIT

https://ibb.co/DkL7NZ4

Describing my question more precisely:
The yellow object is an object that I can move with the arrows.
I want the code to press the key to the left as long as the middle of the yellow object will be in a specific place indicated by each blue dot, i.e. first it will move with the left arrow to n1, then with the right arrow to n2, etc. after n5 the function returns to the beginning of the loop and starts move to n0 (start / finish) then it will repeat until the end of the round. I depend on the function that will be pressed so long because every circle the yellow object moves at different speeds, it can be 1px / s and 10px / s

This is not a browser application or an application that may be interfered with by python so I would like to do it more like python analyze what is happening on the screen and press the keys

Comment: Check [The Locate Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions).

Comment: where do you display this image? if you display it with some Python script then maybe you could do it in different way. Or if you display it in web browser them you could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why are there two n5 points?

Comment: I forgot to change my oversight to 6, this is just a diagram to illustrate what I want to achieve